# Use jquery to hide an element

Tags: jquery

I have a div, "#settings-icon". When you click on "#settings-icon" another div, "#settings-drop-down-wrap", is shown. Now, I added in an if statement to a click event that hides "#settings-drop-down-wrap" if you click anywhere but "#settings-icon". But, for some reason I cannot seem to get it to work correctly, and I am unsure what I could be doing wrong.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/5Zen5/

My JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#settings-icon").click(function() {
        $("#settings-drop-down-wrap").show();
    });
    $('body').click(function (event) {
        if (event.target.id != 'settings-icon') $("#settings-drop-down-  
 wrap").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to stop proagation, use this code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#settings-icon").click(function(e) {
        $("#settings-drop-down-wrap").show();
        e.stopPropagation()
    });
    $(document).click(function (event) {
        $("#settings-drop-down-wrap").hide();
    });
});
```

I've change the target of the event listener to `document` instead of the body because the body may not take the full height.

The problem with your code is that the target is not `#settings-icon`, but his children. Your condition will always be false.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5Zen5/2/

Answer (score 0):

[Try this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/5Zen5/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#settings-icon").click(function () {
        $("#settings-drop-down-wrap").show();
    });

    $(document).click(function (event) {
        if (!$(event.target).parents('#settings-icon').length > 0) {
            $("#settings-drop-down-wrap").hide();
        }
    });

});
```